# Joining List on Carriage Return

Tags: list, join, tcl, newline, carriage-return

In TCL, when joining a list on a carriage return like so:

```
set myList {{a} {b} {c} {d} {e} {f} {g}}
puts [join $myList \r]
```

The output printed to the screen is:

```
g
```

If I instead  do the following:

```
set myList {{a} {b} {c} {d} {e} {f} {g}}
puts [join $myList \n]
```

The output is

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

What makes the use carriage return "\r" in the join only produce "g" while the use of newline "\n" gives me everything in the list?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Tcl: You can see the same thing at a bash prompt: `echo -e 'a\rb\rc\rd\re\rf\rg'` -- pipe that command into `od -c` and you'll see the universe is unfolding as it should.

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with the output than with Tcl `join`. Your output (a console/shell for example) may not be able to display carriage return.

For instance, if you do:

```
set myList {{a} {b} {c} {d} {e} {f} {g}}
set result [join $myList \r]
puts [string length $result]
```

You get 13 as the output, showing that the string is correct.

If you can change the output location to a text file for example, and then open the file in an editor that can recognize carriage return as a character that denotes a change in line (I used notepad++ to test), you'll see the output is fine.

Comment: Consoles typically treat a bare `\r` as an instruction to move to the beginning of the current line and begin overwriting there.

Comment: To see that this is actually happening, try using different length elements, like: `set myList {aaa bb c}`